# Can BCP copy data directly from table to table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I've got a situation where I need to copy several tables from one SQL Server DB to a separate SQL Server DB.  The databases are both on the same instance.  The tables I'm copying contain a minimum of 4.5 million rows and are about 40GB upwards in size.

I've used BCP before but am not hugely familiar with it and have been unable to find any documentation about whether or not you can use BCP to copy direct from table to table without writing to file in between.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

EDIT: The reason we're not using a straightforward INSERT is because we have limited space on the log drive on the server, which disappears almost instantly when attempting to INSERT.  We did try it but the query quickly slowed to snail's pace as the log drive filled up.

Comment: If it's two databases on the same instance, why not use `INSERT`?

Comment: Several reasons including speed of operation and the amount of space we have on the log drive. INSERT swells the log files super quick and we run out of space on the log drive.

Comment: I normally do this sort of `INSERT` in batches of, say, 10,000 rows.

Comment: How does the speed of the INSERT operation usually compare to BCP out to file and then import? So essentially running the INSERT at least 45 times (given our 4.5 million + row count), each time shrinking the log files after completion?

Comment: BCP inserts data in batches the same way as you would with `INSERT`, and has the same sort of transation log considersations. The difference is that BCP must physically copy data off the database server and back on again, whereas with `INSERT` you're moving data around within the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCP is for dumping to / reading from a file. Use DTS/SSIS to copy from one DB to another.

Here are the [BCP docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) at MSDN

Comment: I was looking to find out whether it could be used to copy directly or not, from this, that's a no.  Fortunately, I managed to move some files around and free up enough space to use BCP to move the data around. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

from my answer at [Table-level backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680552/table-level-backup)

I am using [bcp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to achieve table-level backups

to export:

```
bcp "select * from [MyDatabase].dbo.Customer " queryout "Customer.bcp" -N -S localhost -T -E
```

to import:

```
bcp [MyDatabase].dbo.Customer in "Customer.bcp" -N -S localhost -T -E -b 10000
```

as you can see, you can export based on any query, so you can even do incremental backups with this.

Comment: Is there a way to BCP from one table directly to another, or do you have to write a data file then read from a data file?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Import/Export wizard will do the job ... just connect twice to same database (source and destination) and copy one table onto other (empty and indexed), you might want to instruct to ignore autonumeric Id key field if exists. This approach works for me with tables over 1M+ records.

Answer (score 0):

TableDiff.exe might do what you want

https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/automatically-compare-and-synchronize-sql-server-data/