# How can I temporarily disable constraints on my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

After going through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql), I am trying to add the following command in my stored procedure:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

But the editor underlines it and shows this error:

```
SQL70005: The ALL option cannot be used to modify constraints. You must use individual constraint names instead
```

I'm using VS2013 Express for Web with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems like the error is self explanatory; you can not dsiable ALL constraints on a table in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: So which version are they talking about? The question is HUGELY popular and no one has pointed this out anywhere.

Comment: In fact I googled the error message and didn't get any results :). Can't believe I'm the first in the world to experience this. If this behavior was changed in some particular version, this must have been documented somewhere.

Comment: You have to use the entire command `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"` The `EXEC sp_msforeachtable` part is important.

Comment: @abhi: Even though i'm not a stored procedures guru, I can't believe that would be the case. Any reason why u think so?

Comment: I just tried this out in my version of sql server 2008 R2.

Comment: @abhi, he's not executing this for all tables

Comment: and he's having SQL Server Express installed

Comment: @dotNET, can you script your database and paste the script here?

Comment: wow that would be a huge task. I did it the other day. the sql file was over 9MB.

Comment: The error could be a result of having an unique constraint on the table. This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foof1745145-182d-4301-a334-18f799d361d1.aspx). DEFAULT, PRIMARY KEY, and UNIQUE constraints cannot be disabled.

Comment: For me, at least, it was never causing an issue.

Comment: Really weird. I abandoned the VS2013 editor and opened the same stored procedure in Management Studio, which didn't show any errors. I completed my stored procedure's body and saved it to the DB. Now I came back to VS2013, opened the stored procedure again and now it is not showing any errors. Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Check this link if it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639868/temporarily-disable-all-foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

you can write a script that will generate all the statements for you to disable each one (and hten re-enable as appropriate.