# Database Filegroups - Only restore 1 filegroup on new server

Tags: sql, database, restore

Is there a way to backup certain tables in a SQL Database?  I know I can move certain tables into different filegroups and preform a backup on these filegroup.  The only issue with this is I believe you need a backup of all the filegroups and transaction logs to restore the database on a different server.

The reason why I need to restore the backup on a different server is these are backups of customers database.  For example we may have a remote customer and need to get a copy of they 4GB database.  90% of this space is taken up by two tables, we don’t need these tables as they only store images.  Currently we have to take a copy of the database and upload it to a FTP site…With larger databases this can take a lot of the time and we need to reduce the database size.

The other way I can think of doing this would be to take a full backup of the DB and restore it on the clients SQL server.  Then connect to the new temp DB and drop the two tables.  Once this is done we could take a backup of the DB.  The only issue with this solution is that it could use a lot of system restores at the time of running the query so its less than ideal.

So my idea was to use two filegroups.  The primary filegroup would host all of the tables except the two tables which would be in the second filegroup.  Then when we need a copy of the database we just take a backup of the primary filegroup.
I have done some testing but have been unable to get it working.  Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: In addition to clarifying which database servers/editions/releases are being used on each end, you might, if it's still possible, consider adding more specific tags like sql-server if you're working with multiple releases, or sql-server-2005 if you're working with only one. This will help to attract viewers who are choosing questions to answer based on which ones seem to fall more clearly within their area of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your approach using 2 filegroups seems reasonable.

I suppose you're working with SQL Server on both ends, but you should clarify for each which whether that is truly the case as well as which editions (enterprise, standard, express etc.), and which releases 2000, 2005, 2008, (2012 ? ).

Table backup in SQL Server is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680552/table-level-backup,) a dead horse that still gets a good whippin' now and again. Basically, that's not a feature in the built-in backup feature-set. As you rightly point out, the partial backup feature can be used as a workaround. Also, if you just want to transfer a snapshot from a subset of tables to another server, using ftp you might try working with the bcp utility as suggested by one of the answers in the above linked post, or the export/import data wizards. To round out the list of table backup solutions and workarounds for SQL Server, there is this (and possibly other ? ) third party software that claims to allow individual recovery of table objects, but unfortunately doesn't seem to offer individual object backup, ["Object Level Recovery Native" by Red Gate"](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-olr-native/). (I have no affiliation or experience using this particular tool).

As per your more specific concern about restore from partial database backups :

> I believe you need a backup of all the filegroups and transaction logs
>   to restore the database on a different server

1) You might have some difficulties your first time trying to get it to work, but you can perform restores from partial backups as far back as SQL Server 2000, (as a reference see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177425%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

2) From 2005 and onward you have the option of partially restoring today, and if you need to you can later restore the remainder of your database. You don't need to include all filegroups-you always include the primary filegroup and if your database is simple recovery mode you need to add all read-write filegroups.

3) You need to apply log backups only if your db is in bulk or full recovery mode and you are restoring changes to a readonly filegroup that since last restore has become read-write. Since you are expecting changes to these tables you will likely not be concerned about read only filegroups, and so not concerned about shipping and applying log backups

You might also investigate some time whether any of the other SQL Server features, merge replication, or those mentioned above (bcp, import/export wizards) might provide a solution that is more simple or more adequately meets your needs.