# How to export text data from a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, export, etl

I am trying to use the MS SQL Server 2005 Import/Export tool to export a table so I can import it into another database for archival. One of the columns is text so if I export as comma-delimited, when I try to import it into the archive table, it doesn't work correctly for rows with commas in that field. What options should I choose to ensure my import will work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over a year later, I now have an ideal solution to my data export needs, thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363/sql-server-2005-export-table-programatically-run-a-sql-file-to-rebuild-it/228957#228957)

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM CustomerTable" queryout "c:\temp\CustomerTable.bcp" -N -S SOURCESERVERNAME -T 

bcp TargetDatabaseTable in "c:\temp\CustomerTable.bcp" -N -S TARGETSERVERNAME -T -E
```

- -N use native types
- -T use the trusted connection
- -S ServerName
- -E Keep identity values specified in the data file

Very quick and easy to embed within code.

Answer (score 2):

I never use the comma delimter unless the client requires it. Try using | as a delimter. YOu can also use the text qualifier if need be.

Comment: this will have the same problem as using comma-delimited. if any row has a | in it, it won't import correctly. this case is much less common than having a , but still common enough to not work correctly

Comment: I do hundreds of imports a week from 50 or sixty different clients and only a couple of times have we had data with a | in it. In those cases we used ~ as the delimter or added the text qualifier. And in one case we asked them to fix the one offending record in a 20 million record file to avoid having to change the process. If you are exporting, you have control of the data and can find the records with a | and fix them to use some other character instead before you do the export. Much harder to do this with comma because of the meaning of the data when commas are used vice when |s are used.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes as text qualifier

Text qualifier:
Type the text qualifier to use. For example, you can specify that each text column be surrounded with quotation marks.

Comment: I tried using quotes as text qualifier too but most of my rows have a " in it anyways. From what I can tell, the exported data can't escape the existing "s