# export all sql table records in vs 2005 (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, sql-server-2005-express, export-to-csv, export-to-text

Programmatically using vb.net, could we export all records of a sql table into a txt file at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread on the topic has over 100 posts!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/546f4407-0aa4-4b04-96f3-e6f0ba39a9d1

This similar thread may prove valuable:

[SQL Server 2005 - Export table programmatically (run a .sql file to rebuild it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363/sql-server-2005-export-table-programatically-run-a-sql-file-to-rebuild-it)

and 1 more resource...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/31a15a51-f557-499c-96a9-df7faccde98d