# Transfer table between two SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2005 - Export table programatically (run a .sql file to rebuild it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363/sql-server-2005-export-table-programatically-run-a-sql-file-to-rebuild-it)

I always using xls files to transfer data between two tables. But this way is very horrible. Any alternatives? Note: There is no direct network connection between the servers.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into SQL Data Compare from RedGate. It will make your life much easier. Per no direct network connection, you can save the comparison in a script, and execute it on the other server.